# Insert into table with foreign key Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
Customer (Customer_id, Customer_Name)

Customer_Phone (Cus_id, Cus_Phone)
```

I have this two tables and these are connected with a foreign key

I want to insert data to both tables can i do that with one sql statement

The Customer_id in the Customer table is auto Incremented.

This is a one to many relation

i tried `INSERT INTO Customer ("Admin","123456")`

Please Help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two tables, you can insert values to single table at a time. But you can combine multiple inserts in a sql query.

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (1,"Customer1"),(2,"Customer2");
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_PHONE VALUES (1,"133443736466"),(1,"6464747373"),(2,"5664747478");

Comment: But the Id is auto incremented in customer table i cannot enter that manually thats where i am stuck for like 2 days

Comment: INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(Customer_Name) VALUES ("Customer1"); SET CustomerId = LAST_INSERT_ID();INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_PHONE VALUES (CustomerId,"133443736466"),(CustomerId,"6464747373");If you want to insert phone no for multiple customers at a time, then you need to create a stored procedure with transaction block and just handle it.